# extends keyword in docker-compose deprecated?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

According to the docs https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-3, the `extends` keyword has been removed in docker compose `v3`.

Anyways, the docs also clearly show the usage of the `extends` keyword in the most recent docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/extends/

So, can extends be used as is will be supported in future? Or should it be avoided as it is officially deprecated?

Answer (score 2):

There is a fourth major version of the Compose file format, the [Compose specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).  This was re-released in combination with a rebuild of the Compose tool itself.

Historically, Compose file version 2 had options more oriented towards single-system deployments, and version 3 had options more oriented towards Docker Swarm deployments.  The "specification" format generally supports both sets of options, and ignores the `version:` specifier.

For `extends:` in particular, the [specification definition](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#extends) of it doesn't mention it as deprecated, and as you note it has a dedicated page in the standalone Compose documentation.  I'd consider it safe to use.